# Confusion regarding the initial position of the pointer in a list iterated by the Iterator interface

Tags: java

where is the initial index of the pointer to the list should it not
        be the first item of the list.

does the next method

(1)returns the next element of the and points to the next element
        or 
(2) return original element and sets the pointer to the next element.

but if (1) is true then the pointer is on the first element then the first element cannot be returned i.e if (1) is true the pointer should be before the first element i.e in
        some kind of -1 position.

on the other hand if (2) is true then we can remove the first element but we cannot get the next element by usingthe next because we will reduce the index by 1;

which brings me to the next question does remove() method reduce the index by one or keeps it same??

The contextual code is given below::

```
package iterators;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Array_practice {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        Iterator<Integer> iterator= list.iterator();
        iterator.remove();//does not work why??

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add some line breaks? It's difficult to understand when it's written in such a style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> where is the initial index of the pointer to the list should it not be the first item of the list

No. It is *before* the first item of the list. You only get to the first item when you call `next()` for the first time.

In fact, it's usually simpler to think of the iterator as *between* items. So for example, with your list:

```
  1   2   3
^              // Initial position
    ^          // After calling next()
        ^      // After calling next()
            ^  // After calling next() the third time - now hasNext() will return
               // false
```

Then [`remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) - as documented - removes the item that was last returned.

You're calling `remove()` before *any* items have been returned... so there's nothing to remove.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc for the Iterator interface is as follows :

> void remove()
>
> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next(). The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

So using remove() before having ever called next() will never return an element.  This of course is if the class you're iterating respects the contract for implementing Iterable - which is obviously the case of ArrayList and other java.util collections.